# Changing the TCP initial congestion window value in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bandwidth, tcp, broadband

I would like to do some testing with the TCP Initial congestion window on Windows 10 Pro, but it seems the settings are disabled in the Pro version:

```
Set-NetTCPSetting -SettingName InternetCustom -InitialCongestionWindow 64
```

Is there a workaround? Any tool that allows me to change the value?

I am getting the following error message in Windows PowerShell:

```
Set-NetTCPSetting : Property InitialCongestionWindow is read-only
```

I have a 500Mbit cable internet connection, and I often feel that the TCP Slow Start mechanism is throttling my bandwidth too much at the beginning of a download or speed test. It often takes up to 5-6 seconds until a download reaches the full 500Mbit/s speed.
This might not be on my end, hence I would like to test with different InitialCongestionWindow-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Powershell command documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/set-nettcpsetting?view=windowsserver2022-ps) says:

> ```
>     On Windows 10, the following parameters are read-only and cannot be modified:
>
>     - MinRtoMs
>     - InitialCongestionWindowMss
>     - AutomaticUseCustom
>     - CongestionProvider
>     - CwndRestart
>     - DelayedAckTimeoutMs
> ```

According to [this forum post](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1271672-set-nettcpsetting-still-incomplete-code-in-windows-10/), the limitation was added already in Windows 7.